# Rx.Net - Get stock price changes and process them

Tags: system.reactive

The problem I'm trying to solve

1. Get stock ticks
2. Always consider *latest* stock price
3. Each ***x*** second take a *snapshot* of ticks and send for processing

So I have an `Observable` source of stock ticks. It sends only the ticks for stocks I'm interested in. What I need to do is to receive these stock prices, and after each **x** seconds (for the sake of example let's say every 3 seconds) send a *snapshot* of prices for processing. If within 3 seconds I receive 2 ticks for the same stock, I only need the latest tick. This processing is compute heavy, so if possible I would like to avoid sending same stock price for processing twice.

To bring an example.

Let's say at the beginning of sequence I received 2 ticks -> **MSFT:1$, GOOG:2$**.

In the next 3 seconds I receive nothing, so **MSFT & GOOG** ticks should be sent for processing.

Now the next second I receive new ticks -> **MSFT:1$, GOOG:3$, INTL:3$**

Again let's assume within next 3 seconds nothing comes in.

Here, since **MSFT** price didn't change (it's still 1$), only **GOOG & INTL** should be sent for processing.

And this repeats throughout a day.

Now I think Rx helps to solve this kind of problems in easy & elegant way. But I'm having a problem to have the proper queries.
This is what I have so far, will try to explain what it does and what's the issue with it

```
var finalQuery =
               from priceUpdate in **Observable<StockTick>**
               group priceUpdate by priceUpdate.Stock into grouped
               from combined in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
                      .CombineLatest(grouped, (t, pei) => new { PEI = pei, Interval = t })
               group combined by new { combined.Interval } into combined
               select new
               {
                   Interval = combined.Key.Interval,
                   PEI = combined.Select(c => new StockTick(c.PEI.Stock, c.PEI.Price))
               };

            finalQuery
                .SelectMany(combined => combined.PEI)
                .Distinct(pu => new { pu.Stock, pu.Price })
                .Subscribe(priceUpdate =>
                {
                    Process(priceUpdate);
                });

public class StockTick
{
   public StockTick(string stock, decimal price)
   {    
      Stock = stock;
      Price = price;
   }
   public string Stock {get;set;}
   public decimal Price {get;set;}
}
```

So this gets the stock price, groups it by stock, then combines latest from this grouped sequence with `Observable.Interval`. This way I'm trying to ensure only latest ticks for a stock are processed and it fires up every 3 seconds.

Then again it groups it up by interval this time, as a result I have group of sequences for each 3 second intervals that passed.

And as a last step, I flatten this sequence to sequence of stock price updates using `SelectMany` and also I'm applying `Distinct` to ensure same price for the same stock is not processed twice.

There are 2 issues with this query I don't like. First is I don't really like double group by's - is there any way to avoid it ? Second - with this approach I have to process prices one by one, what I really would like to have is *snapshots* - that is within 3 seconds whatever I have I will bundle and send for processing, but can't figure out how to *bundle*.

I'll be happy for suggestions to solve this problem other way, but I would prefer to stay within Rx, unless there is really something much much better.

Comment: In your example you don't send Microsoft because it didn't change, but neither did Google and you sent that. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Enigmativity apologies for confusion, meant to write **GOOG:3$** ... will update the post now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things:

1. You'll want to take advantage of the [`Sample`](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Sample) operator:
2. You probably want `DistinctUntilChanged` instead of `Distinct`. If you use `Distinct`, then if MSFT goes from $1, to $2 then back to $1, you won't get an event on the third tick.

I imagine your solution will look something like this:

```
IObservable<StockTick> source;
source
    .GroupBy(st => st.Stock)
    .Select(stockObservable => stockObservable
        .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
        .DistinctUntilChanged(st => st.Price)
    )
    .Merge()
    .Subscribe(st => Process(st));
```

**EDIT** (`Distinct` performance problems):

Each `Distinct` operator has to maintain within it, the full distinct history. If you have a high-priced stock, for example AMZN, which so far today has ranged from $958-$974, then you could end up with a lot of data. That's ~1600 possible data points that have to sit in memory until you unsubscribe from the `Distinct`. It also will eventually degrade performance, as each AMZN tick has to be compared to the 1600-ish present data points before going through. If this is for a long-running process (spanning multiple trading days), then you'll end up with even more data points.

Given N stocks, you have N `Distinct` operators that need to operate accordingly. Multiply that behavior by N stocks, and you have an ever-increasing problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me try this and get back to you. On a relative note, I do want `Distinct`, as I mentioned I process the prices, so the same price shouldn't be processed twice irrespective when the price was received.

Comment: You may want to be careful of the memory implications there.

Comment: Memory implications ? Could you please elaborate a bit ?

Comment: Thank you for help. Just replacing `DistinctUntilChanged` with `Distinct` as I explained before does what I need. I'm marking your post as answer, but would really appreciate if you could comment on `memory implications` you mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thank you for edited answer. To not make this a discussion, would you say what you explained in edited post does not apply to `DistinctUntilChanged` ? `YES / NO` answer will also suffice and I will take it from there.

Comment: Correct. `DistinctUntilChanged` takes up O(1) space, `Distinct` takes up O(n), where n in this case is number of prices observed for each stock.